# UIAlertView wait until name entered

Tags: ios, multithreading, uialertview

I have small problem, it looks like thread can sort it, but I'm not good in threads, I read many tutorials, but still didn't get idea how to sort it. Scenario is: I am saving file to Amazon s3, and it's working perfect, but i decide before uploading the file to amazon, give for user to enter  file name, and when i call UIAlertView class, program keep running, and saving file as @"test.txt". Here is a part of the code:

```
fileNmae = @"test.txt";
fileName = [self getFileName];
NSLog(@"File name is %@", fileName);

/// -----------------------------------
/// Uploading file to Amazon cloud !!!!
/// -----------------------------------
...
```

and here alert method:

```
-(NSString*) getFileName {

     // some alert method

return @"someFile.name";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Definitely you should edit your question to be more readable and clear. Also, post the code that you are using and it's causing you problems, don't post random pice of code.

Comment: I dont understand your requirement. 
Are you planning to ask the user to enter the filename in AlertView ?
Or what ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getFileName will call alert and its delegete methode will be called when user press OK.
Implement delegate of alertView in .m as

```
@interface ViewController :UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

and call back method is

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    /// -----------------------------------
    /// Uploading file to Amazon cloud !!!!  Once user press OK on alert upload will start
    /// ----------
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that the solution. Sorted.

Answer (score 0):

No need of thread here. Implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` method and put the uploading task in

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Uploading file to Amazon cloud !!!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you doing cannot achieve this.The way to implement it is to make the alertview first and get the filename and after that go for uploading

```
fileNmae = @"test.txt";
```

1. After this show alertview
2. In its delegate clickedButton... you can get the file name and then
   upload the file from there

For alertview with text

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Please enter someth" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[av textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
[av show];
```

implement the delegate methods for textfield as well as alert